# Change or add value to props through custom directive on Vue 3

Tags: vuejs3, directive

I have this need to make control of a component props/data by a **[custom directive](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-api.html#component)**. My first approach was to change the instance on binding time, but the rendered component does not got the values added. Here is what I have tried.

```js
export const renderDirective = {
    created(el, _, vnode) {  
       _.instance.$options.$data.someValue = 'Some Value';
    }
};
```

Is there some effective way to change/add values to $data/$props instance within a custom directive, (Vue 3)?

Comment: I don't understand this use case, why can't you just provide a prop to the component which would be straight forward and better to understand by other devs?

Comment: The purpose is: take control of some utilities witing a component from a framework on a level that the final user will not have to handle.

Comment: But a directive needs to be added by the user of this framework as well, same as a prop. To my understanding directives are meant to do some DOM stuff, like autofocus and not for passing data into a component. That's what props are for. I am not sure this will work.

Comment: It is a real use of case where will be provided to the user some $data that only the framework may offer to him. 

It is not about what the user wants to change or control, but what the framework will give to him as $data utilities.

Comment: yeah agree real use case, the user should not have to pass props himself, a directive is way better, the user just add it to the component and it's done